# Recipe database with ingredients table

Tags: database

I am currently, making a project which gathers data from user profiles and to filter out query results depending on the data.

So i have a family account, which have different family members. Users would fill out basic information regarding health of each member. These information will then be used to query the results. An example would be if a family member has a diabetes.. When the family account tries to browse recipe, instead of showing the user all the recipes in the database, it would just instead show recipes that are not risky to diabetic persons.

Whats the best way of constructing the database for recipe.

Table 1 = recipe
Table 2 = ingredients

For each ingredient in the recipe, they would have their own table that would define their nutritional value so that i could effectively determine which recipes to filter out. How would i construct the column for ingredients? if each ingredients need to have their own table.

Comment: Why would each ingredient need its own *table*? Each ingredient would be a *row* in an `ingredients` table. The table would have the ingredient name, nutritional information (available from the USRDA, btw), etc.

Comment: That is exactly what i meant, i may have used the wrong term, in turn made a whole new meaning.. But that is what i wanted, so how do i construct the column for ingredients in my recipe table if i want to link that(Fk) to another table for each ingredients for nutritional facts

Comment: Please update your question to make sure accurately reflects what you are trying to attempt based on feedback from @DaveNewton.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a join table, e.g., `recipe_ingredients`,

```
recipe_id | ingredient_id
    1     |      1             -- Recipe #1 has ingredients 1, 2, 3
    1     |      2
    1     |      3
    2     |      2             -- Recipe #2 has ingredients 2, 5
    2     |      5
```

You could also have an `order` or `index` column if you wanted to explicitly order the ingredients.

You might want to consider spending some time reading up on SQL/RDBMS basics, since this is about as low-level as it gets.

Comment: I knew what i was up against. My project seems to tackle more on database. No wonder why i was assigned an adviser who specializes in DB. I am just building a mock database for recipe for now so i could be able to code my html part. I would then have to refine the structure of my database.


Thanks for this.